# New version of gem not reflecting in gemfile.lock of an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I'm updating the rails version of my application from '4.2' to '6.0'. There are multiple engines in my application. The new rails version is not reflecting in the gemfile.lock of engine which is causing the following error on running `bundle update rails` command:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 6.0.3, ~> 6.0)

    admin was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
       customer was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
          emails was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
             rails (~> 4.2)
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this error or simply how to update the rails version in gemfile.lock of an engine?

Comment: Have you checked the gemspec of the engine in question?

Comment: No. Actually I've only changed the root gemfile. Do I have to change the version in gemspec too?

Comment: That won't change the requirement of the rest of the gems listed in your Gemfile. If these engines are created by you you need to update the rails requirement in the gemspec and release a new version of the gem. If not you need to fork them and do the same.

Comment: **IMPORTANT SIDENOTE:** I would highly recommend you upgrade slower, in steps, e.g. 4.2 => 5.0 => 5.1/5.2 => 6.0. Jumping from 4.2 to 6.0 is going to be hellish and fraught with traps. You will miss deprecation warnings (which will then remove methods), the API will have had dramatic changes twice (once for each major version), etc.  [Read Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-upgrade-process)